# Usage of ました form and た form with こと

Tags: grammar, politeness

Example:
Is the formal of にほん に いった こと が ありまづ this : にほん に いきました こと が ありまづ. Or is the first one used in both cases?

Comment: ありまづ should be あります.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **V-た form + ことがある** is the formula to say about past experience of doing something

In にほん に いった こと が あります 
It's already formal since the ある is written as あります。**You cannot change the いった to いきました** when using this pattern。It should only be V-た form. And note that ある in the end cannot be changed into past form あった since you still have the experience until now.

Comment: It's not strictly true that the ある can't be あった: 高校ん時、海外に行ったことがあった.

Comment: It's being taught that way when we talk about experience of our past. Since when we are talking about it, we still have the experience so it couldn't be あった. In reality, it should be more flexible i think...

Comment: It's nearly the same difference as "have been" and "had been" in English IMO. In both cases the former tends to be more common.

Comment: In context, it might seem that way. But the literal meaning is to have a possesion of something. In this case posses experience. So if you use あった it means you had a possession of something (past, and you don't have it anymore now). As in 'I had a dog'.The dog died and you don't have it anymore. Although it's very tempting to search for English equivalent, in japanese case if we try it, usually it might have given us quite confusion... :)